# Setting Action Bar title and subtitle

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to set title and subtitile of my action bar before compile time.
I got a way to do it like this:

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
ab.setTitle("My Title");
ab.setSubtitle("sub-title");
```

But I don't want to do it on run time. Is there any xml file or any location where I can specify these titles?

I am trying to achieve this:

[image]

### Edit:

The reason why I want it in xml is that I want my app to be supported in API level 8. And the method getActionBar() is supported at least on level 11.

Comment: you question is not clear because `Is there any xml file or any location where I can specify these titles?`  yes you can specify titles  in strings.xml

Comment: You can specify a custom layout for your action bar.

Comment: @A--C .. can you please provide a tittle example? I am sorry, this is my first day on Android. I've been looking all over the project files. But I've no idea how to do it. A little example might give me a better idea.

Comment: @AdilMalik : see [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/274639-android-actionbar-tutorial/) example

Comment: ρяσѕρєяk's link shows an xml approach. However runtime it's still easier.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяk the example sets the title of the menu items. I want to set the title of Action bar. As shown in the image attached in the OP.

Comment: @AdilMalik : then add [support-library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) to make support in lower version for ActionBar

Comment: Do you know how to remove subtitle? Because simple setSubtitle(""); doesn't work.

Comment: @Malachiasz by default there is no sub-title. Just comment out your `setSubtitle("");` and then try

Comment: I know. But it doesn't solve my problem. I have to first show subtitle and later hide it.

Comment: @Malachiasz this should work: `abActionBar.setSubtitle(null);`

Comment: thx. Why haven't I try that :)

Comment: @Malachiasz don't worry, it happens ;-)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can do something like this to code for both versions:

```
/**
 * Sets the Action Bar for new Android versions.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void actionBarSetup() {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setTitle("My Title");
    ab.setSubtitle("sub-title"); 
  }
}
```

Then call `actionBarSetup()` in `onCreate()`. The `if` runs the code only on new Android versions and the `@TargetApi` allows the code to compile. Therefore it makes it safe for both old and new API versions.

Alternatively, you can also use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) (*see edit*) so you can have the ActionBar on all versions. You will have to do some changes such as making your Activities extend `SherlockActivity` and calling `getSupportActionBar()`, however, it is a very good global solution.

### **Edit**

Note that when this answer was originally written, `ActionBarSherlock`, which has since been *deprecated*, was the go-to compatibility solution.

Nowadays, [Google's `appcompat-v7` library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) provides the same functionality but is supported (and actively updated) by Google. Activities wanting to implement an [`ActionBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html) must:

- extend `AppCompatActivity`
- use a `Theme.AppCompat` derivative

To get an `ActionBar` instance using this library, the aptly-named `getSupportActionBar()` method is used.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Unfortunately I cannot use ActionBarSherlock. I'd love to use that. But currently I am having a strange error: `Unable to resolve target 'android-14'`. For now I'd like to go for the code snippet that you provided. Thanks

Comment: Late to the party, but 'Unable to resolve target' means you don't have that API SDK installed. That was like 4.1 or something right?

Comment: @Mgamerz The ActionBar was introduced in `HoneyComb`, but it depends on what Android version the *library* targets. Android 14 is `ICS`

Comment: I see. I get these errors all the time (Google Play Services), but I think its throwing the same message cause it can't find the min SDK, rather than the target on this one.

Comment: Extend AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 16):

The title for the actionbar could be in the AndroidManifest, here:

```
<activity 
    . . .
          android:label="string resource" 
    . . .
</activity>
```

> **android:label** 
>   A user-readable label for the activity. The label is
>   displayed on-screen when the activity must be represented to the user.
>   It's often displayed along with the activity icon. If this attribute
>   is not set, the label set for the application as a whole is used
>   instead (see the  element's label attribute). The
>   activity's label — whether set here or by the  element —
>   is also the default label for all the activity's intent filters (see
>   the  element's label attribute). The label should be
>   set as a reference to a string resource, so that it can be localized
>   like other strings in the user interface. However, as a convenience
>   while you're developing the application, it can also be set as a raw
>   string.

Comment: I guess this is closest to what I want. But I cannot specify the sub-title of sub-label this way. If I could specify sub-title somehow, my problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 13):

Try this one:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
ab.setTitle("This is Title");
ab.setSubtitle("This is Subtitle");
```

Answer (score 5):

There is another option that no one commented, from the Support Library V7 was implemented by Google `ActionBarSupport`, which is compatible `ActionBar` from Android 2.2 to the last.
If you change your `ActionBar` this you can do `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("")` on all Android versions.

Answer (score 3):

Nope! You have to do it at runtime.

If you want to make your app backwards compatible, then simply check the device API level. If it is higher than 11, then you can fiddle with the ActionBar and set the subtitle.

```
if(Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 11){
    //set actionbar title
}
```

Comment: yes you can.... getResources().getString(R.string.title) and getResources().getString(R.string.subtitle)

Comment: I hope that you realize that you will still be setting the ActionBar title at run time. He's asking if you can do it completely in XML, so you must have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 3):

Try This:

In strings.xml add your title and subtitle...

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
ab.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.myTitle));
ab.setSubtitle(getResources().getString(R.string.mySubTitle));
```

Comment: didn't feel like it... OP is asking for an xml file

Comment: The reason why I want it in xml is that I want my app to be supported in API level 8. And the method getActionBar() is supported at least on level 11.

Answer (score 3):

```
    <activity android:name=".yourActivity" android:label="@string/yourText" />
```

Put this code into your android manifest file and it should set the title of the action bar to what ever you want!

Comment: You saved my day.This is the best solution

Answer (score 3):

**Try This**

Just go to your Manifest file.
and You have define the label for each activity in your manifest file.

```
<activity
        android:name=".Search_Video"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

here change

android:label="@string/your_title"

Answer (score 3):

```
supportActionBar?.title = "Hola tio"
supportActionBar?.subtitle = "Vamos colega!"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is trivial one-liner in Kotlin

`supportActionBar?.title = getString(R.string.coolTitle)`

Answer (score 0):

For an activity you can use this approach to specify a subtitle, along with the title, in the manifest.

**Manifest:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/my_title"
    android:description="@string/my_subtitle">
</activity>
```

**Activity:**

```
try {
    ActivityInfo activityInfo = getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    //String title = activityInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
    int descriptionResId = activityInfo.descriptionRes;
    if (descriptionResId != 0) {
        toolbar.setSubtitle(Utilities.fromHtml(getString(descriptionResId)));
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Could not get description/subtitle from manifest", e);
}
```

This way you only need to specify the title string once, and you get to specify the subtitle right alongside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the title in action-bar using `AndroidManifest.xml`. Add label to the `activity`

```
<activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:label="Your Title" />
```