# How to give separate name to app at display and main activity in android

Tags: android

How to set different application name and activity name in android app.

I want to give application name to be displayed as XYZ and when i start application it should show ABC on the title bar of activity.

Comment: are u using ActionBar??

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297178/setting-action-bar-title-and-subtitle

Comment: Use [setTitle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle(int))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in AndroidManifest you have the label tab for both activity and application.
set them both.
and in the intent filter for the activity you will also need to specify the label:

**intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name"**

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.your.activity.name"
        android:label="@string/activity_name" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set different label under `application` tag and `activity` tag in your manifest file.

Try this

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="XYZ" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TestConnect"
        android:label="ABC" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

If you want to display app name from `string.xml` then you need to do this.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TestConnect"
        android:label="@string/activity_title_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Also add those strings in `string.xml` inside `res/values/` directory just like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">XYZ</string>
  <string name="activity_title_name">ABC</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use resource utilisation in this case.
Declare the various names to be used in your **strings.xml** file and use them at appropriate places in the **AndroidManifest.xml**.

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/main_activity_title" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
```