# Android: How to set different layout title and titlebar icon image

Tags: android

I have 5 layout views in Eclipse Android application. I want to show different layout title and title icon image(in top left corner) in all the Graphical Layouts, not programmatically.

Currently, it is showing the same app title in all the layouts and also app icon image in all the views.

```
<application android:name="singleton"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
```

I tried Login activity title label as below, login_name is already added in string: But, this is not showing any title there.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.myappandroid.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/login_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Please advise, how to fix this thru Graphical layout?

Comment: what kind of layouts? activity? Mind that the "actionbar" (where the title & icon is displayed) belongs to an Activity. So, via XML, you can only assign their text on <application> / <activity> . If you need to change the title/icon in the middle of an activity, you have to do it the programmatic way. But it's really simple, just getActionBar().setTitle("hi") will do it at the activity level, or ((Activity)getContext()).getActionBar().setTitle() at any view level. Or you can define different activities, each one with different layout, icon & title

Comment: Thank you! I tried this.setTitle("Login"); it is working.

Comment: very good !! :) Mind that if you do this.getActionBar(). ... you can change more things in the actionbar: icons, colors, etc...

Comment: Unfortunately, if i use like "this.getActionBar().setTitle("login")" it is giving error, not able to build it.

Comment: mmm strange, check "this" is the activity. It does work, plus you can also do setSubtitle() .... check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297178/setting-action-bar-title-and-subtitle and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: Actually this is solved. This is due to setting min level API issue, I did like, Right click on the project folder > Android tools > Clear Link Markers

Answer (score 0):

Do you say u want your own customize icon and title at the action bar.If yes then i will mention what i did for this...
1.first i create a customize xml file 
2.ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
 actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);//use this to load your own action bar
 actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

Well what i did recently in my project is..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>//first i created a xml file for the ui i need
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TopBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#E6E7E9" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/baricon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>

ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();// then i call this part in my activity
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
enter code here
```