# Nullpointer exception in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am getting the null object reference of action bar while calling the `setTitle` function. This is my code

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.transport.transport.R;

public class registration extends Activity {
     ActionBar actionbar=getActionBar();
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.registrationpage);
          actionbar.setTitle("ramkumar");
     }
}
```

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297178/setting-action-bar-title-and-subtitle

Comment: Don't call getActionBar(); before onCreate method. Initialize actionbar variable in onCreate method.

Comment: ActionBar actionbar=getActionBar(); should be mentioned within onCreate. Why are you doing that before it? Place it within onCreate and it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Change code like this:

import android.app.ActionBar;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;

        import com.example.transport.transport.R;


         public class registration extends Activity {
        ActionBar actionbar;
        @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.registrationpage);
   actionbar=getActionBar();
    actionbar.setTitle("ramkumar");
}
  }
```

Comment: nice answer...thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

**You are not initializing the Action bar correctly. Implement following changes to your code**

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.example.transport.transport.R;

public class registration extends Activity {
     ActionBar mActionbar;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.registrationpage);
          //Initializing Action bar   
          mActionbar=getActionBar();
          mActionbar.setTitle("Your Title");
     }
}
```

If you are using supported Action Bar Library then you can change `getActionBar()` to `getSupportActionBar()`to add lower versions support