# Setting The title of the Item Selected on ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

Hello I've been trying to make the title of the ActionBar to show the Title I've selected in the navigationDrawer. I'm attaching the code please help me in this.
What I've right now is this:
 - I've a navigation Drawer having certain title imports,gallery.
Problem is :
 - When I select one item of the navigation drawer it doesn't show the title name on the action bar which makes my app look incomplete.
What I need is:
 - To have the item name visible on the ActionBar/ToolBar which is selected by me.
This is my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

NavigationView navigationView;
Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //set the fragment initially
    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Fragment_Layout,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Fragment_Layout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        SecondFragment fragment = new SecondFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Fragment_Layout,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

The images are before and after selcting the ttle in the navigation drawer.
Before:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo8we.png)

After selcting gallery as you can see the second button on the page comes up button in the ActionBar it was still showing Welcome. Please help me in that. 
After:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkIiX.png)

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: They changed the navigation drawer layout to use a `Toolbar` rather than `ActionBar` as per previous. read more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Action Bar title and subtitle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297178/setting-action-bar-title-and-subtitle)

Answer (score 1):

Add Text View Inside the toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Toolbar Title"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorWhite"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Disable the title of toolbar.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Set the title of custom textview

```
((TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title)).setText(title);
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getSupportActionBar();
 actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
 actionBar.setTitle("Narnia");
```

You could create a method and then in onNavigationItemSelected and call the method with the title you want.