# Open a fragment from another fragment always keeps the previous fragment title

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on an Android app that has only one Activity and 8 Fragments. MainActivity has a DrawerLayout with a menu that opens each of the fragments.

Sometimes I need to navigate from one fragment to another directly, I mean, after executing some methods on a fragment, I need to open one of the other fragments.

For example, the user opens fragment B from the side menu, then the users executes some methods on fragment B, and after execution, fragment C should be open.

It works fine, my only issue is that fragment C keeps the fragment title from fragment B, and I need to show the original title from fragment C.
This is how am I going from fragment B to fragment C

```
HomeFragment nextFrag= new HomeFragment();
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .replace(R.id.frame, nextFrag,"findThisFragment")
             .addToBackStack(null)
             .commit();
```

Comment: what you mean keep title, where?

Comment: @Remario, each fragment has a title in the navigation bar. The fragment C opens fine, but keeps the title from fragment B

Comment: whats the logic for updating the drawer title?

Comment: @Remario, I don´t want to change the drawer title. I mean: fragment B has a title at the navigation bar "QUIERO", and fragment C has the title "EST". When fragment C is opened from fragment B, the title at fragment C is "QUIERO", not "EST" as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean **Action bar title** you should consider that the title is set on main activity only once and also **if** you need the title depend on your current fragment your should create a function in your main activity in order to set the title again otherwise the title won't be change .

[Here is the complete answer of how to change the title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297178/setting-action-bar-title-and-subtitle)